# Adding an array of JComponent extended objects to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I'm begining with JFrame, I'm triying to make a StarField, for the moment I'm adding the Star JComponent to the Starfield JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Star extends JComponent{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    private final Color color = Color.YELLOW;

    public Star(int x, int y) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       g.setColor(color);
       g.fillOval(x, y, 8, 8);
    }   
}
```

and the StarField code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class StarField extends JFrame{
    public int size = 400;
    public  Star[] stars = new Star[50];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StarField field = new StarField();
        field.setVisible(true);
    }

    public StarField() {
        this.setSize(size, size);
        for (int i= 0; i< stars.length; i++) {
            int x = (int)(Math.random()*size);
            int y = (int)(Math.random()*size);
            stars[i] = new Star(x,y);
            this.add(stars[i]);
        }       
    }
}
```

The problem it's thar it only print one star, I think it is the last one, the coords are working like they are supposed to do it, so I think the mistake is in the JComponent or JFrame implementation, I'm self-learning, so maybe my code isn't the correct way for using swing.

Thank you, and sorry for my english, I'd tried to write it the best I know.

Comment: Better have a look at `LayoutManager`. If I remember correctly the default `Layout` is `BorderLayout` which allows a total of 5 components at 5 different spots. `this.add(stars[i]);` overwrites every component previously added as you can only have one component at the `BorderLayout.CENTER` (which is default and therefore will magically appended to your `add` call, so that it actually is `this.add(stars[i], BorderLayout.CENTER);`)

Comment: Suggestions for the OP to improve the custom component: 1) don't hardcode the color. Instead you can use the setForeground(...) method to set a color for the oval and then use getForeground() when doing the painting. Then each oval can be a different color. 2) Don't hardcode the size. Make this a parameter. Then each oval can be a different size. 3) implement the `getPreferredSize()` method.  This would be based on the parameter suggested in 2. This is used by layout managers to determine the size of the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you cannot use a layout manager, and need to reset it to null. See the my code below

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class StarField extends JFrame {
    public int size = 400;

    public Star[] stars = new Star[50];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StarField field = new StarField();
        field.setVisible(true);
    }

    public StarField() {
        this.setSize(size, size);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        // usually you should use a normal layout manager, but for your task we need null
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * size);
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * size);
            stars[i] = new Star(x, y);
            this.add(stars[i]);
        }
    }

    public class Star extends JComponent {

        private final Color color = Color.YELLOW;

        public Star(int x, int y) {
            // need to set the correct coordinates
            setBounds(x, y, 8, 8);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+) for addressing the layout issue and improved painting code so that the painting is always done at (0, 0).

Comment: `In your case you cannot use a layout manager` - FYI. You could consider using the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/). It allows you to position components at a random location while still providing some layout functionality such as setting the size of a component and determining the preferred size of the panel, so it will still work in a scroll pane. This class would assume the getPreferredSize() has been implemented correctly as suggestion in my comment to the original question.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the info. Probably I'll use it somewhere. And big thanks again for the WrapLayout ;)